# Can bugs in token contracts without "transfer" affect someone's "real" assets?

Tags: vulnerability

I wonder if token contracts without `transfer` (or `send`, `call`) can affect someone's "real" assets (not the tokens).

For example, the contract from:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc5d105e63711398af9bbff092d4b6769c82f793d#code

is known to have an integer overflow vulnerability at line 261:
(CVE-2018-10299: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-10299)

However, this contract does not have code that sends Ethers to some contracts.

In such cases, how can bugs have bad influences on someone's real money?

Comment: What do you mean with "real money"? Ethers? Fiat?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I wanted to say any of the two. But it seems they can be exchanged each other, can't they? (e.g., https://fx-rate.net/ETH/USD/). Do I have to differentiate them in the context of real money?

Comment: Well, you can't input fiat into a smart contract, so yes there is a difference. So let's consider Ethers

Comment: @SunbeomSo The bugs allows anyone to mint a large amount of tokens diluting  the value to legitimate token owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if a contract is not meant to handle Ether, people don't send it Ethers. It's an accident if they do, and then the Ethers are typically stuck there forever, since there is no way to transfer Ethers out of the contract. The Ethers are then considered lost for good.

If a contract is meant to handle Ethers, it should have all the necessary functionality to transfer it also out, with some logic. This logic can of course have bugs, which may mean that the Ethers gets stuck in the contract or that undesired parties get access to the Ether

However, if we are talking about centralized exchanges, they handle assets differently. When you trade in a centralized exchange, the underlying assets are not transferred inside the blockchain at all - they are only transferred inside the exchange's databases. Only when you request to withdraw your assets, a real transaction is created and the assets are sent to your desired wallet address. So asset trades inside centralized exchanges don't rely on the tokens' coded transfer functionality and therefore possible bugs in the token code don't also matter - until the tokens are withdrawn from the exchange.

Comment: In the article below, it is said that "... BEC was trading at $0.32 per token, which makes the total dollar value of the exploit around $3.7 novemdecillion ..." : https://cryptoslate.com/batchoverflow-exploit-creates-trillions-of-ethereum-tokens/  where the address of the BEC contact is in my original question. Can tokens be exchanged without relying on code in related contracts? The article seems to suggest this.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how that is related to this answer. The answer is not related to tokens

Comment: I agree with your answer in general, but I still wonder how the bug in the contract without ``transfer`` could affect exchanges, as stated in the article (my first comment on this answer is edited)

Comment: Ah, you are talking about centralized exchanges. This is the first time you mention it, so I was only answering based on smart contracts in general. Added a section about centralized exchanges in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems I have to investigate about centralized exchanges more. In your updated answer, "therefore possible bugs in the token code don't also matter - until the tokens are withdrawn from the exchange." <= does this mean that, if some tokens are withdrawn from the exchange, bugs in the token code (without ``transfer``,``send``,``call``) can affect someone's Ethers (or other types of assets)?

Comment: No, token code can only affect assets which the token contract holds. If nobody sends Ethers there, it can't affect them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128209/discussion-between-sunbeom-so-and-lauri-peltonen).